# Why the C structure definition in the implementation file is unavailable?

Tags: c

I give the following example to illustrate my question:

1) `a.h` where the structure is declared

```
 a.h 
   struct A_Structure;
    typedef struct A_Structure *A_Structure_Ptr;
```

2) `b.c` where the structure definition is implemented

```
 #include "a.h"

 struct A_Structure
 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

 };
```

2) `main.c` where the structure is invoked

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"

int main ()
{
   struct A_Structure b;
    return 0;

}
```

However, I cannot compile these C codes as I receive the following error message:

```
>main.c(6): error C2079: 'b' uses undefined struct 'A_Structure'
```

Any ideas? Thank in advance.

**EDIT**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "a.h"

int main ()
{
   struct A_Structure *b=0;
   b=(struct A_Structure*)malloc(12);
   b->a=3;
   free(b);
    return 0;

}
```

I tried to create the structure in this way but still failed.

Comment: Yes, use pointers. Using the struct directly would require knowing its *size* and to know that, the *definition* is needed.

Comment: You should include b.h in either a.h or main.c

Comment: because b.h is never included..

Comment: Kishan you are confused and your advice is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need this:

```
struct A_Structure
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

};
```

in a.h

This is the typical approach when defining `struct`s

If you're trying to implement an [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), you need a function that instantiates `A_Structure` and returns a pointer, as well as functions that manipulate `A_Structure` pointers:

in a.h

```
A_Structure_Ptr CreateA(int a, int b, int c);


void FreeA(A_Structure_Ptr obj);
void SetA_a( A_Structure_Ptr obj, int a );
int  GetA_a( A_Structure_Ptr obj );
// etc.
```

in b.c

```
A_Structure_Ptr CreateA(int a, int b, int c)
{
     A_Structure_Ptr s = malloc( sizeof(A_Structure) );
     s->a = a;
     s->b = b;
     s->c = c;
}

void FreeA(A_Structure_Ptr obj)
{
    free( obj );
}

void SetA_a( A_Structure_Ptr obj, int a )
{
    obj->a = a;
}
```

in main.c

```
int main ()
{
    struct A_Structure *b = CreateA( 1, 2, 3);
    SetA_a( b, 3 );
    FreeA(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This *could* be the case, but the question doesn't say it.

Comment: Well, it's unclear if the OP is trying to just write code that works, or he has a reason for putting the `struct` in the header file (because he's using someone else's code that does that).  I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

When you put the structure *declaration* in a header file, but leave the *definition* in the .c file, this is known as using an [*opaque pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) API.

In an API like this, consumers only use pointers to the objects. Only the implementation needs to know the size or contents of the object. This is how you do OOP in C, and is key to *information hiding* which provides better decoupling of components. Here's a more complete example:

**foo.h**

```
struct foo;    // forward declaration

struct foo *foo_create(void);
void        foo_use(struct foo *f);
void        foo_destroy(struct foo *f);
```

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

struct foo {
    int a, b, c;      // Consumers don't know about these!
};

struct foo *foo_create(void)
{
    struct foo *f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
    if (!f)
        return NULL;

    *f = (struct foo) {
        .a = 1,
        .b = 2,
        .c = 3,
    };
    return f;
}

void foo_use(struct foo *f)
{
    // something with f->a, f->b
}

void foo_destroy(struct foo *f)
{
    free(f);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    struct foo *f;   // As a consumer of foo, we can only use **pointers**

    f = foo_create();
    if (!f)
        return 1;

    // I cannot access the members of `struct foo` here.
    // In an opaque API, the struct members are considered
    // an implementation detail and cannot be used outside
    // of the implementation.

    foo_use(f);

    foo_destroy(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Considering the usage in `main.c`, you're probably wrong and the OP doesn't want opaque pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide whether you want to hide the details of the structure from the "outside" or not. If you don't want to hide them, just put the structure definition in `a.h`. Hiding it ensures better decoupling and central control of your `b.c` over the content, but that means you have to provide a way to create an object in `b.c` (e.G.

```
struct A_Structure *create_A_Structure(void);
```

and use this from the outside.

an unrelated stylistic advice: better don't `typedef` pointers. While your `_Ptr` suffix makes it kind of obvious, it's still better to just *have* the asterisk everywhere because that is what C programmers are used to, so the fact that it's a pointer is obvious *at the first glance*.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
/* header */

typedef struct A A;

A *A_create(void);



/* implementation */

struct A
{
    int foo;
}

A *A_create(void)
{
    return malloc(sizeof(A));
}
```